# Git add files in symbolic link directory (windows)

Tags: windows, git, symlink

#### Description

For a work project, I have a git directory in `C:\_work\project-name` for the code. Then I also have a directory for documentation in `C:\Users\Local-Admin\OneDrive\project-name`. The documentation directory has a symlink in the code/ git repository (`C:\_work\project-name\_Documents`) and links to the directory in OneDrive.

#### What I want

Now I want to add the Word, ... files to git (I have to), but it just allows me to add the symlink folder. How can I do this?

#### Notes

In my git config file is `symlinks = true`

It's important, that the documentation folder must be in OneDrive because of Word, Excel, ... and the code not because otherwise it syncs `node_modules`.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my own question by just trying around and remembering a fail I had, when I linked a folder to OneDrive and flooding my OneDrive with it.

### Solution

I copied my documents to `C:\_work\project-name\_Documents` (normal folder). Then I linked the `_Documents` folder to `C:\Users\Local-Admin\OneDrive\project-name`.

Now I have a symlink in my OneDrive (linking to the code/ git folder) instead in the code/ git folder linking to my OneDrive, and it works so far.